# Deleting an address and relationship with customer

Tags: customer, customer-address, magento-1.9.2.1

When fetching a customer's addresses and deleting them in a foreach loop:

```
$addresses = $customer->getAddresses();

foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $address->delete();
}
```

The addresses appear empty in the customer's address book on the frontend and also in the customer admin section. So the address has been deleted, but the relation to the customer still exists.

When taking a look at `Mage_Customer_AddressController::deleteAction` nothing more seems to happen than what I am doing, but the addresses don't seem to appear as empty addresses anymore.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: What kind of relation still exists ?

Comment: When I go to Customers > Addresses, I see this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zyva7xx4uaxc2e0/Screenshot%202016-02-04%2017.56.17.png?dl=0. Seems that the address is still linked to the customer's address book, but empty. Same goes for address book on the frontend.

Comment: $customer->cleanAllAddresses();
$customer->save();

Seems to do the trick. Very undocumented, though, and still does not answer why deleting an address leaves a blank address associated with the customer...

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea... try

```
$addresses = $customer->getAddresses();

foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $address->setCustomerId(null)->save();
    $address->delete();
}
```

Comment: Gives me SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails [...]